# DataFrame and Lists returning empty after re-running script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape data from 1001TrackLists, a website that lists tracks in DJ mixes, using BeautifulSoup.

I wrote a script to collect all track information and create a dataframe which worked perfectly when I first finished it and returned the dataframe as expected. However, when I closed my jupyter notebook and restarted Python, the script returns a blank dataframe that only returns the column headers. Each list in the for loops that I created which I used to build the dataframe are also blank.

I've tried restarting my kernel, restarting/clearing output, and restarting my computer - nothing seems to work.

Here's my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url_list = ['https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/yj03rk/joy-orbison-resident-advisor-podcast-331-2012-10-01.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/50khrzt/joy-orbison-greenmoney-radio-2009-08-16.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/7mzt0y9/boddika-joy-orbison-rinse-fm-hessle-audio-cover-show-2014-01-16.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/6l8q8l9/joy-orbison-bbc-radio-1-essential-mix-2014-07-26.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/5y6fl1k/kerri-chandler-joy-orbison-ben-ufo-bbc-radio-1-essential-mix-07-18-live-from-lovebox-festival-2015-07-24.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/1p6g9u49/joy-orbison-andrew-lyster-nts-radio-2016-07-23.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/qgz18zk/joy-orbison-dekmantel-podcast-081-2016-08-01.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/26wlts2k/george-fitzgerald-joy-orbison-bbc-radio-1-residency-2016-11-03.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/t9gkru9/james-blake-joy-orbison-bbc-radio-1-residency-2018-02-22.html', 'https://www.1001tracklists.com/tracklist/2gfzrxw1/joy-orbison-felix-hall-nts-radio-2019-08-23.html']
djnames = []
tracknumbers = []
tracknames = []
artistnames = []
mixnames = []
dates = []
url_scrape = []

for url in url_list:
    count = 0
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.103'}
    page_link  = url
    page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(page_response.content, "html.parser")
    title = (page_link[48:-15])
    title = title.replace('-', ' ')
    title = (title[:-1])
    title = title.title()
    date = (page_link[-15:-5])
    tracknames_scrape = soup.find_all("div", class_="tlToogleData")
    artistnames_scrape = soup.find_all("meta", itemprop="byArtist")
    for (i, track) in enumerate(tracknames_scrape):
        if track.meta:
            trackname = track.meta['content']
            tracknames.append(trackname)
            mixnames.append(title)
            dates.append(date)
            djnames.append('Joy Orbison')
            url_scrape.append(url2)
            count +=1
            tracknumbers.append(count)
        else:
            continue
    for artist in artistnames_scrape:
        artistname = artist["content"]
        artistnames.append(artistname)

df = pd.DataFrame({'DJ Name': djnames, 'Date': dates, 'Mix Name': mixnames, 'Track Number': tracknumbers,'Track Names': tracknames, 'Artist Names': artistnames, 'URL':url_scrape})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line 38th line from `url_scrape.append(url2)` to the following and it works:

```py
url_scrape.append(url)
```

Otherwise you get `NameError: name 'url2' is not defined`.

Comment: Could I ask you a follow up question on the same error occurring when I only slightly modified the script?

Comment: Sure. Maybe use gist , pastie, or pastebin to share the modified code via a comment?

Comment: if you go to my profile, I posted the follow up question as a separate question if that works?

Comment: The comment someone added didn't fix it?

Comment: No, it did not unfortunately